# Optimal way to get a jsonObject's non Existent Attribute

Tags: java, json, jira-rest-api

I try to collect data from JIRA through a REST API.

I can get a jsonArray with JSONObjects. These JSONObjects may contain attributes a;b;c;d. Some JSONObjects may contain only for example a;b;c missing the attribute d.

I am trying to collect these attributes within the code. Since for some JSONObjects some attributes are missing, I may get such an error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["d"] not found.
```

I used a try/catch method (seen down below) and thus I avoid the error Message by ignoring it.

Is there a nicer method to use for such a problem?

```
JsonNode jsonNode = response.getBody();
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonNode.getArray();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
String startDate = (String) jsonObject.get("startDate");
String releaseDate = (String) jsonObject.get("releaseDate");
Integer projectId = (Integer) jsonObject.get("projectId");
String description;
// getting the error for the attribute description
try {
    description = (String) jsonObject.get("description");
} catch (Exception e) {
    description = "";
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a `custom object` with the member variables of your JSON so that you can `deserialize ` your JSON into your `custom object`, then all you will have to do is check if the `description` member variable is `null` or nor

Comment: @NickAth thanks for the input. I did not know that such a thing is possible. Cheers.

Comment: Could you add into your question a `json sample you receive?` Are using `gson` library?

Comment: @NickAth `{"archived":false,"releaseDate":"2019-07-16","name":"test 1.0","self":"https://test/rest/api/latest/test/10000","userReleaseDate":"16/Jul/19","id":"10000","projectId":10000,"released":true}` This is a json I am getting from JIRA through an API call. The classes I use are the following `JsonNode jsonNode = response.getBody();` and 
`JSONArray jsonArray = jsonNode.getArray();` Using the following lib `import org.json.JSONArray;` and
`import org.json.JSONObject;`

Comment: check the answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `custom object` and `deserialize` the `json string` into an instance of this object. I will show below a solution using `gson` library

**Maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**Model class**

```
public class Model {

private boolean archived;
private String releaseDate;
private String name;
private String self;
private String userReleaseDate;
private long id;
private long projectId;
private boolean released;

//getters && setters ommitted 

public Model(){

}
```

Then you can `deserialize the JSON string into the Model class like this`

```
String json = "{\"archived\":false,\"releaseDate\":\"2019-07-16\",\"name\":\"test 1.0\",\"self\":\"https://test/rest/api/latest/test/10000\",\"userReleaseDate\":\"16/Jul/19\",\"id\":\"10000\",\"projectId\":10000,\"released\":true}";
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Model model = gson.fromJson(json, Model.class);
```

This way, you will not have to check each time each parameter separately to assign it to the corresponding member variable.